# Set initial value of hibernate GenerationType.IDENTITY

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using hibernate GenerationType.IDENTITY which translates to auto_increment in tables. When I insert data using spring data jpa a very high number is being used for auto incremented id value. But when I do inserts using direct sql insert queries on db it is assigning a very low number. So the auto incremented values are not consistent. Because of my database (Memsql) I can't use sequence generator as it does not allow that. How can I ensure a low value for id which also consistent between the hibernate application and raw queries?

Comment: Provide more details like the SQL statements that you are seeing, entity definition, DDL and code that you are using.